# Conveting .htaccess to Ngix rules

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I need to convert htaccess file to nginx config. I http://winginx.com/en/htaccess but an error occurred when I update the nginx config file.

The htaccess file reads:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?king-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

and it was converted to

```
# nginx configuration
 index index.php;
 location / {
 rewrite ^(.*)//(.*)$ /%1/%2 redirect;
 if (!-e $request_filename){
 rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?king-rewrite=$0&$query_string break;
 }
}
```

now the error is:

Failed to save configuration file : Configuration is invalid : nginx: [emerg] unknown “0” variable nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two lines that are wrong at least:

First:

```
rewrite ^(.*)//(.*)$ /%1/%2 redirect;
```

Correct one would be:

```
rewrite ^(.*)//(.*)$ /$1/$2 permanent;
```

In nginx, you reference the captured regexes with $n, where n starts from 1. `permanent` equals to `301` redirect. `redirect` is `302` redirect.

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?king-rewrite=$0&$query_string break;
```

Correct one would be:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?king-rewrite=$1 last;
```

Here, `$1` is the captured regex. In nginx, you don't need to append query string separately to rewrites, they are automatically appended. If you don't want existing query string appended to the rewritten URL, then you add `?` after the rewritten version. `last`  means that no further rewrite rules will be considered.

A more sophisticated configuration according to nginx best practices would be like this:

```
location ~ ^/(?<part1>[^/]+)//(?<part2>[^/]+)$ {
    rewrite ^ /$part1/$part2 permanent;
}

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?king-rewrite=$request_uri;
```

Here, we use named regex captures in the `location` directive to capture the parts of the path to variables.

Then we use `try_files` directive to first check if the requested URLs exist, if not, pass the request to index.php.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I used:

    location ~ ^/(?<part1>[^/]+)//(?<part2>[^/]+)$ {
       rewrite ^ /$part1/$part2 permanent;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?king-rewrite=$request_uri;

Comment: Hi Tero, Can you help with this please? http://serverfault.com/questions/713957/convert-htaccess-rewrite-rule