# Convert htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I want to convert this to nginx rules

```
# BEGIN EAP Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?a=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /new/404.php
</IfModule>
# END EAP Rewrite
```

I have tried several, but no luck.

```
error_page 404 /new/404.php;
    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?a=$args; 
        #rewrite  ^/(.*)?$  /index.php?a=$1 last;
    }
```

Actually, this line below worked for the URL but real folder paths, like css and js, are not working.

```
#rewrite  ^/(.*)?$  /index.php?a=$1 last;
```

Anyone?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `try_files $uri $uri/` directive checks if files / directories exist on the filesystem, and serves them if they exist.

If you don't want to serve any files directly, you should try to set up a reference to non-existing path, so that `try_files` cannot find any files, and then use something like this:

```
location / {
    root /path/of/empty/directory;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?a=$args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried it but it's not working as well. I even did <?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
die; ?> and I got array(1) { ["a"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: I am getting array(1) { ["a"]=> string(40) "/product/product-name.html" }. The problem was the preceding slash i.e '/product' . How can I make it return array(1) { ["a"]=> string(40) "product/product-name.html" } instead of array(1) { ["a"]=> string(40) "/product/product-name.html" }